# PHP isset() $_POST не работает

Tags: php, html, post, form

Постоянно выводит false

```
<form class="signup-and-login-form signup-form" action="/signup.php" method="POST">
                        <?php if(!empty($errors)){
                                echo array_shift($errors);

                            }
                            if(isset($_POST['do-signup'])){
                                echo 'true';
                            }else{
                                echo 'false';
                            }
                            ?>

                    <input type="text" class="input-form has-sucsess" placeholder="Введите логин" name="login" id="login">
                    <input type="password" name="password" placeholder="Введите пароль"  class="input-form" id="password">
                    <input type="password" name="confirm_password" placeholder="Введите пароль"  class="input-form" id="confirm_password">
                    <label for="do-signup" name="signup" class="do-signup-label">SIGN UP</label>
                    <input type="submit"  name="do-signup" value="displey-none" id="do-signup">
                </form>
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22579616/

Comment: Попробуй проверить свой код используя var_dump($_POST['do-signup'])

Comment: Лучше сделайте просто var_dump($_POST) чтобы узнать почему не работает

Answer (score 1):

1. echo false; - не выведет ничего на экран надо использовать var_dump(false);
2. Функция isset() - хитрая... Даже если переменная пустая - определена как пустая строка, то вернёт true.
3. И может быть попытка общения с сервером 2-мя методами GET и POST одновременно... Тогда нужно принимать не ПОСТом и ГЕТом, а $_REQUEST... Ссылка на документацию (рекомендую потренироваться с var_dump, чтоб видеть как это работает изнутри): https://www.php.net/manual/ru/reserved.variables.request.php

Comment: `echo false; - не выведет ничего...` - так у автора строка с false, нет?

Comment: Если я правильно понял вопрос... То! У автора, после проверок if... Есть вывод: echo false; И я написал, что это не правильно, безсмысленно. Использовать надо не echo, a var_dump(), чтоб увидеть какой-то результат в браузере.

Comment: В этом есть смысл чтобы просто посмотреть передаётся что-то или нет, это не есть не правильно или бессмысленно. `echo 'false';` тоже показывает результат в браузере, а не один var_dump()`

Comment: После var_dump($_POST);
Вывело:array(3) { ["login"]=> string(4) "1234" ["password"]=> string(8) "12345678" ["confirm_password"]=> string(8) "12345678" }
А после var_dump(flase);
bool(false)

Comment: Вот! Значит методом пост идёт передача, var_dump() - это показал... А ошибка в самом использовании isset()... Эта функция не имеет смысла, потому что $_POST['do-signup'] — ЕСТЬ! Просто там пустая строка.